# lock message queue for a dedicated Actor

Tags: locking, akka.net

I'm looking for a way to lock the message queue in akka.net.

I have a dedicated Actor that performs a request data / read response with an external component (with state), it does only that (no logic)

I have an actor A which sends messages to the dedicated Actor. According to the content of the response it can ask send speficic messages.

There is also an actor B who sends messages to the dedicated Actor, but with other logic, other functionality, but the same applies here, depending the response, send a specific new request.

But the messages send to the dedicated Actor can not be mixed.  So Actor A can use the dedicated Actor, and when finished, Actor B can start sending messages to the dedicated Actor.

Is there a mechanism to lock the message queue of the dedicated Actor?

Thanks in advance,

Lintie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Akka a standard way of doing postponing other messages to be handled until a specific message arrives, is to use [stashing](https://getakka.net/articles/actors/receive-actor-api.html#stash). You simply stash all incoming messages until the one that you're waiting for arrives, and then unstash them back onto actor's mailbox in the order they've arrived.